$\displaystyle\lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0}\cos \left( \dfrac{\pi \theta }{\sin \theta }\right) =?$
$\displaystyle\lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0}\cos \left( \dfrac{\pi \theta }{\sin \theta }\right) =?$
Apparently, $\displaystyle\lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0} \cos\left(\dfrac{0}{0}\right)$, so we can't use L'Hospital Rule here. Moreover, $\displaystyle\lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\pi \theta }{\sin \theta }=\pi$

Not much effort or thought shown I must say. -1

By continuity, you have
$$
\lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0}\cos \left( \dfrac{\pi \theta }{\sin \theta }\right) = \cos \left( \lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\pi \theta }{\sin \theta }\right)
$$
Since you already know the value of that inside limit, the conclusion is obvious.

For the general cases, can we say the following? $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(g(x))$ is equal to $f (\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x))$ if $f$ is continuous at $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$?

Yes. For metric spaces, this is often given as the definition of continuity, more or less.
